# Expo push notifications.- no funcionan notificaciones cuando la App corre por atrás o esta en la vista que genera la función de notificación

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Hola a todos construí una aplicación con React Native y expo, implementé la notificación push de expo y todo parece funcionar. Logré crear la notificación push, pero cuando probé en mi iPhone, la notificación no llegó. Sé que el código funciona porque la función async devuelve una respuesta ok 200.

Incluso, en un momento en que la notificación llegó a mi teléfono, pero no puedo recibir una notificación en mi iPhone si la pongo en segundo plano o si estoy en la vista que activa la función de notificación.

Aquí está mi código (a pesar de que creo que no es un problema de código, aunque sea una confusión de concepto)

```
getNotificactionToken();

})

 const getNotificactionToken = async () =>{// THIS ASYNC FUNCTION INSERT INTO FIREBASE DATABASE THE TOKEN OF NOTIFICATION
            const {status: existingStatus} = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
            console.log(existingStatus);
            let finalStatus = existingStatus;

            if(existingStatus !== 'granted'){
                const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
                finalStatus = status;
            }

            if(finalStatus!=='granted'){
                return;
            }

            let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
            token = JSON.stringify(token.data).slice(1, -1);

            //setNotificationToken(token)

            if(token){ //WE SEND TO FIREBASE BAKEND THE TOKEN
            const resp = await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('1')
            .doc('Q6vBYWYcUrAnlxNYBkji')
            .set({token}, {merge: true});
             }

             notify(token);
        }

    const notify =(token) => { // THIS ASYNC FUNCTION EXECUTE THE NOTIFICATION ITSELF ON THE DEVICE, REMEMBER DEVICE SIMULATORS DO NOT SHOW NOTIFICATION, THEY ARE NOT SUPPORTED
                console.log("HERE 4 **********: " + `"${token}"`)
                const message = {
                 to: token,
                 title: "Hi world",
                 body: "something",
                 sound: "default"
                };

                const options =  {
                   method: 'POST',
                   body: JSON.stringify(message),
                   headers: {
                                  Accept: 'application/json',
                                  'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                }
                }

                fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', options) 
                .then((response)=>{ return response.json()})
                .then((data)=>{console.log("resp: " + JSON.stringify(data))})
                .catch((error)=>{ console.log(error)})


              }
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Acá no usamos mayúsculas sostenidas. Por favor, edita el título.

Comment: y de paso ponelo en español

Comment: Ok gracias por la sugerencia, es mi primera consulta en stack overflow. Lo que sucede es que siempre consulto esta página y todo esta en ingles, así que supuse que debía poner en inglés la consulta.

Comment: Hola parece que hay un atributo que hay que cambiar para que la notificación llegue en foreground, pero por alguna rzon pese a la docmentación igual no  me funciona 'const message = {
                 to: token,//"ExponentPushToken[J7t6TCPxhGT-GG5R6WGEeI]",
                 title: "LEGALIS",
                 body: "Un nuevo cliente te esta esperando",
                 sound: "default",
                 ios: { _displayInForeground: true }
                };'